# Build book on Travis and push back to GitHub pages

Tags: r, travis-ci, bookdown

I am writing a book using `bookdown` which is hosted on GitHub and one frustration is I keep forgetting to build the book before I push my changes back to GitHub. So one solution I came up with was to use Travis to build and deploy my book to the `gh-pages` branch. I am using `htmlproofer` to check the links in my book so I need my Travis build to use the `ruby` language and not `R`. I cannot see how to access the `Rscript` command, however, since it is not installed on the environment. My current `.travis.yml` is

```
language: ruby
rvm:
  - 2.3.3
before_script:
  - chmod +x ./scripts/cibuild.sh
script:
  - ./scripts/cibuild.sh
deploy:
  provider: pages
  skip_cleanup: true
  github_token: $GITHUB_TOKEN # Set in travis-ci.org dashboard
  local_dir: docs
  on:
    branch: master
env:
  global:
    - NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES=true
notifications:
  email: false
sudo: false
```

Where `cibuild` is just a `bash` script containing

```
#!/bin/sh

Rscript -e "bookdown::render_book('index.Rmd', 'bookdown::gitbook')"
htmlproofer ./docs
```

I tried using a `sudo apt-get install r-base` but this gave me `R` version `2.14.1` which is far too old...

Any ideas?

Comment: Add R from a PPA? https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/installing-dependencies/#Installing-Packages-from-a-custom-APT-repository

Comment: So `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/rdev`? Then `sudo apt-get install r-base`? That should give me the latest version right?

Comment: Probably need `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/rdev` then `sudo apt-get update -yy`, then finally `sudo apt-get install r-base`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve this, I switched to a `language: R` build since this also comes with Ruby. The answer is detailed [here](https://nathaneastwood.github.io/2017/05/16/automatically-building-testing-and-deploying-bookdown-with-travis-and-github-pages/)